# PHP - starting to use namespaces

Tags: php, open-source, namespaces

**Can you provide me the name of a good (easy-to-analyze) open-source project(-s) that use namespaces instead of PEAR file structure naming conventions?**

I'm willing to start using namespaces in my project, but I don't really know how should I handle this in the best possible way, e.g.:

Autoloading class will autoload my internal classes using namespaces, but what about autoloading 3rd party modules which don't use namespaces, or namespaces mirroring its file structure? Should I create two separate classes, or handle this behaviour in a single class?

Flexible file structure - how to name namespaces there? Let's have a namespace in system/ folder like: System/Foo/Bar. But what if someone changes the name of the system/ folder into something else and the namespace will remain the same?

And so on...

Comment: Commonly [PSR-0 autoloaders](http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/) are used nowadays. They're pretty much for shoehorning the PEAR directory/file names onto namespaces 1:1 (they missed to consider PHPs identifiers have different properties than filesystems though). If you have a diverse class mashup - with and without namespaces, a [map-generating autoloader](http://code.google.com/p/mpautoloaderclassmap/) is better suited (syntactically anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSR-0 is one the few standards we have in PHP.

There's lots of examples in the internet, here's some:

- Symfony https://github.com/symfony/symfony
- Composer https://github.com/composer/composer
- Doctrine https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2